# What is test classes in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing, tdd

I came from an IT education background and culture that is not accustomed or familiar with "test driven development". Long story short, I learned programming on Xcode on my current job, and after months of suppressing curiosity about this "test" and "UI test" files that kept appearing every time I created new project, I decided to look for it now that I have the time. That's where I learn the word "test driven development".

But surprisingly, there's so little articles out there for newbies that want to learn the basic concept about test driven development, let alone understand how to do it in Xcode. The articles I can found are all advanced materials, which assume the reader already familiar with TDD. The only QA I found in stack overflow that explain the basic about TDD is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189317/what-is-test-driven-development), and that is not enough explanation because it only explain a very brief of what, not how. And also, it itself is tagged as duplicate to a QA link that's already removed from stack overflow. And the Apple's [own documentation about writing test classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/04-writing_tests.html) also assume that I'm already familiar with the concept either.

Can somebody gives a really simple example on how TDD works in writing Xcode project, particularly in Swift iOS? Like, what is my app code, what is my test code, and how the two are connected or related. I mean, I don't really understand the concept how writing a test code on test classes can help you "debugging" your main code.

Because from what I imagine from my interpretation of "testing", the test code must "simulate" how user enter data on the UI, try every possible combination of input, etc. And also, what's the difference between "test" and "UI test" ? How can code test a UI? Oh, and if you want to tag this question as "duplicate", please also give the link to where the duplicate is. Thanks.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://www.jayway.com/2010/01/15/test-driven-development-in-xcode/) article?

Comment: @RashwanL no I haven't. Wonder why this kind of article wasn't appeared on my searches before.

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/141405/unit-testing-macos-part-12

Comment: @Adrian thanks, this one is great too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Test Driven Development, or TDD for short, is a simple software
>   development practice where unit tests, small focused test cases, drive
>   the development forward. This is most easily explained by the Three
>   Rules of TDD that dictate the following:
>
> You are not allowed to write any production code unless it is to make
>   a failing unit test pass. You are not allowed to write any more of a
>   unit test than is sufficient to fail; and compilation failures are
>   failures. You are not allowed to write any more production code than
>   is sufficient to pass the one failing unit test. That means that test
>   cases are written before any production code. Not all tests are
>   written up front, it’s rather that a small test is written, then a
>   small piece of production code is written that only allows that test
>   to pass. This is repeated in many small iterations: test, fail, code,
>   pass, test, fail, code, pass…
>
> Many people consider TDD to encourage clean code, simple architectures
>   and a stable system that’s actually testable. Plus, it’s also fun!
>   We’ve previously written about various aspects of TDD, but in this
>   tutorial we’ll focus on how it works for XCode projects, where you
>   write apps for Mac and iPhone. We will create a simple XCode project,
>   do some special configuration steps and then demonstrate how TDD can
>   be used to write your app. We’re going to use OCUnit and its framework
>   SenTestingKit, which nowadays is included with Apple’s XCode tools.

Checkout [this](https://www.jayway.com/2010/01/15/test-driven-development-in-xcode/) article that explains how Test Driven Development in XCode works.